# How can I write in this text box using python webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to write something in this email box:

[image]

Here is my part of the code that sends it:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random
import pyperclip

while True:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')


    #Get email Site
    driver.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/');
    time.sleep(5)

    #Click Button
    #bt = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Change')
    #bt.click()

    #Copy Email
    element = driver.find_element_by_id('mail')
    emailtextvalue = element.text
    time.sleep(5)
    pyperclip.copy(emailtextvalue)
    time.sleep(2)

    #Enter Email
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get('https://www.pointsprizes.com/ref/18429434')
    time.sleep(5)

    #This is the problem
    entermail = driver.find_elements_by_name('email').send_keys(emailtextvalue) 
    time.sleep(2)
# enter code here
```

This is supposed to take a random email and put it on the email box on the point prize email box! But send keys will not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')


    #Get email Site
    driver.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/');
    time.sleep(5)

    #Click Button
    #bt = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Change')
    #bt.click()

    #Copy Email
    element = driver.find_element_by_id('mail')
    emailtextvalue = element.get_attribute("value")
    time.sleep(5)
    #If you dont use you dont need copy string
    pyperclip.copy(emailtextvalue)
    time.sleep(2)

    #Enter Email
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get('https://www.pointsprizes.com/ref/18429434')
    time.sleep(5)

    #This is the problem
    entermail = driver.find_elements_by_name('email')[0].send_keys(emailtextvalue) 
    time.sleep(2)
```

I changed your code to this

Comment: Trying it! Give me a sec

Comment: Still does not work. The email does not print inside the text box

Comment: The website you want to pull email have problem I'll try to get innerhtml

Comment: I got! try to get_attribute("value")

Comment: Were do I put that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
entermail = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/input[1]")
driver.implicity_wait(5)
entermail.send_keys(emailtextvalue)
```

Edit: I get X path like [image]

Edit 2: `driver.find_elements_by_name('email')[0]` can work

Comment: Almost their I just got a small error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sudo.py", line 34, in <module>
    driver.implicity_wait(5)
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'implicity_wait'

Comment: I wroted false sorry, the right one is : implicitly_wait(5)

Comment: Ok so it works! But it does not write the email copied

Comment: It writes blank

Comment: change `element.text` to `element.get_attribute("innerHTML")`

Comment: the first one or the second one?

Comment: Witch element.text to I replace? the first time or the second time?